# Copy values from php object to eloquent entity

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, reflection

I am creating an API using laravel 10 and eloquent and I want to copy values from an object read from the http request to anoter object that is a laravel entity, I have an object with a lot of properties and I would like to copy automatically all the properties to another object so I can save the changes to the DB without copying values from request to model using $obj1->name = $request->name for each property in my object.

Let me explain:

I have this class:

```
class Usuarios extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'usuarios';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [... a lot of properties]
}
```

I have this method in my controller:

```
function save(Request $request){
    $data = $request->all();
    $user = new Usuario($data);
    $userFromDB = Usuarios::find($data->id);
    // is there a way to do this? I just want to copy properties 
    // without creating a new object, or is there another way to do this? 
    // using reflection or something like that? or does laravel have 
    // any other way to do this without copying each value??
    copy_values($user,$userFromDB);  //????????????
    $userFromDB->save();
}
```

is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the replicate function of the model.

```php
$user = new Usuario($data);
$user2 = $user->replicate();
```

Cheers

[Replicating Models - Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#replicating-models)

BTW: In your example there is no data saved to the database because you would have to ->save() or ::create($data) the first user.

Comment: thanks, I am using replicate and fill

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable using a package, you can use any Automapper package. I am aware of [Automapper By Mark Gerarts](https://github.com/mark-gerarts/automapper-plus).

Otherwise, a slower technique to use serialization to convert from one type of object to another type of object.

```
$new_object = unserialize(serialize($source_object))
```

Comment: this metod does not combine objects, only clones the object but it is very expensive